# Diffuse Maps and DirectX

Tags: c++, directx

How would I load two diffuse maps onto one mesh. I have a mesh with multiple sub meshes but each one of those sub meshes has a vertex buffer and I don't think that's very efficient. How could I have two diffuse maps on one mesh without having to go into 3d modeling software and merge the Uv coordinates of the two objects. I'm using directX and C++.

Comment: "I don't think that's very efficient" - have you actually benchmarked this?  Until you have hard evidence that it's actually not very efficient, you're indulging in premature optimization.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this in 3D modeling software exactly? That's the normal way of solving this problem.

Comment: Just wanted to know if there was another way to go about it to minimize vertex buffer switches.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Why do you need to switch vertex buffers?  Do the submeshes have different input layouts?

Comment: @MooseBoys May be out of inexperience. But I thought for each distinct mesh you should have a separate vertex buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can even think of accomplishing this would be to add some sort of selector data to the vertex information that would allow a custom shader to select between the two textures to be applied. This technique can be applied with a little custom code to rewrite/combine the two vertex buffers, and of course the custom shader to take the new vertex format and the two textures to be used.